# item.getActionview() always gives null

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have a searchView in the toolbar as an option menu.

Whenever I try to set `setOnQueryTextListener` it gives me a `NullPointerException`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();  //searchView: null item: "Search"
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {  //searchView: null
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            newText = newText.toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<Note> newNotes = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Note note: notes){
                String name = note.getTitle().toLowerCase();
                if(name.contains(newText)){
                    newNotes.add(note);
                }
            }
            noteListAdapter.setFilter(newNotes);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Things that I already did and didn't work:

adding `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }` to proguard file.

Implementing `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` on my Java class.

menu.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android:support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:icon="@mipmap/share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo it should be `android.support` not `android:support`

so use

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

YOU ARE DOING THIS

```
   SearchView search = (SearchView) findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

PLEASE DO THIS

```
SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: I've tried it as well but it still gives me NullPointerException on searchView

Comment: i can clearly see in OP code `menu.findItem(R.id.search);` , can't see the line that you are referring in your answer